# Fish Shell How to change the font colour of Auto-suggestion features?

Tags: terminal, fish

is possible to change the font colours for the Auto-suggestion features in the fish shell terminal?
I want to customize all of that on my own colour
does you guy have any suggestion?

[Screenshot in my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTZpO.png)

Answer (score 2):

Please see the documentation section on "[Syntax highlighting variables](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/interactive.html#syntax-highlighting-variables)":

> The colors used by fish for syntax highlighting can be configured by changing the values of a various variables. The value of these variables can be one of the colors accepted by the set_color command. The modifier switches accepted by set_color like --bold, --dim, --italics, --reverse and --underline are also accepted.

And then later:

> fish_color_autosuggestion autosuggestions (the proposed rest of a command)

So, to change the color of the autosuggestion, change $fish_color_autosuggestion, like e.g.

```
set -g fish_color_autosuggestion blue
```

or

```
set -g fish_color_autosuggestion dd0f00
```